# Помогите найти способ для поиска email-адресов на сайте

Tags: python, selenium

Использую такой способ для поиска email-адресов на сайте, но много на каких сайтах он просто их пропускает. Посоветуйте что-нибудь, чтобы можно было собрать больше адресов!

```
mailto_links = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto")]')
```

Comment: за слово "почт" и отсутствие тегов - "-"

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос вот так: добавил больше аргументов для поиска:

```
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'mailto')]")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[contains(@href,".com")]')
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, ".com")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"href")]')
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href="'+url+'"]')
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]").getAttribute('href')
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ember-view aia-icon").get_attribute("href")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a").getAttribute("href")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,("//input[contains(td[5])]")).getAttribute("href")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "data-table").getAttribute("href")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='testId']/a").getAttribute("href")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td[5]")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,("//input[contains(td[5])]"))
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
mailto_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ember-view aia-icon")
```

Comment: так тут больше половины запросов ищет не имейлы, а непонятно что